# get full date of a specific day of the current week with GNU date

Tags: linux, date, gnu

Is there a way to get the date of Friday of the current week regardless whether it is in the future or past from current day ?

For example, today is `2021-07-10` so Friday of the current week would be one day ago. But if today was `2021-07-05` Friday of the current week would be four days in the future.

I am aware that with `date` utility you can get either last Friday or the coming Friday with :

`date --date="last Friday"` and
`date --date="next Friday"`

is there a way to get the date of Friday of the current week without complicated logic ?

Comment: `date --date="Friday"` ?

Comment: this unfortunately is same as date --date="next Friday". it returns the coming Friday which is next week and not the current week.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do what you want is to do something like the following

```
date -d "next monday - $(($(date +%u) -1)) days"
```

Of course, there are side issues such as which day is the start of the business week (it varies), etc.

Here is a simple script to print out a week's dates:

```
#!/bin/bash

for DAY in monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday
do
   # date -d "next $DAY - $(($(date +%u) - 1)) days"
   date -d "next $DAY - $(date +%u) days
done
```

It produces the following output based on today's date:

```
Mon Jul  5 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
Tue Jul  6 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
Wed Jul  7 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
Thu Jul  8 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
Fri Jul  9 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
Sat Jul 10 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
Sun Jul 11 12:00:00 AM PST 2021
```